# Avoiding OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, json, string, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have code in which I am given a large JSON string (could be anywhere from 50MB to 250MB) that is an array of JSON objects to be parsed and sanitized then serialized to a file. Everything was going fine with 50MB JSON strings but when the string gets over a hundred or so MB my app crashes with OutOfMemoryError. I know I can increase the size of the heap but would like to avoid doing so if possible. I have included some thoughts I have been having recently. I tried moving try blocks around a little bit to no avail.

1) I suspect there is some way to do this with streams but I have no idea how to stream the result String (which is a json array string of json objects) one JSON object at a time.

2) Since result is a Java string, it is immutable. How can we consume this string and get it out of memory ASAP?

3) Would cleanedResult be better to instantiate a new object each time rather than just assign the same object something different each time?

4) At the end of the for loop shouldn't there only be roughly 2x memory used as before the loop as now json stringbuilder variable contains the same memory as the result string which should be the two largest variables in memory?

I have included the code below.

```
String result = getLargeJSONString(...); // function that gives me a large JSON string which is an array of JSON objects
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(); // to hold final JSON values to write to file

// try to parse said large JSON String
JSONArray results = new JSONArray();
try {
  results = new JSONArray(result);
} catch (JSONException j) {
  j.printStackTrace();
}

// do json sanitation on each object and then append to stringbuilder
// note the final result should be a string with a JSON object on each newline
JSONObject cleanedResult = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
  try {
    cleanedResult = JSONSanitizer.sanitize((JSONObject) results.get(i));
  } catch (JSONException j) {
    cleanedResult = new JSONObject();
  }
  json.append(cleanedResult.toString());
  json.append('\n');
}

// write built string to file
try {
  Files.write(Paths.get("../file.json"), json.toString().getBytes());
} catch (IOException i) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Google [`java json stream parser`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+json+stream+parser), and you will find that Jackson has a [streaming parser](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core#overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Of corse* you should prefere streaming over contiguous memory allocation (String, StringBuilder, arrays and so) to process large amounts of data. So your best chance is to use a streaming JSON parser/serializer.

However, you should first try to optimize your code through several easy-gain fixes:

**One**: If you really need to store the result before wrinting it to a file, pre-size the StringBuilder to the estimated maximum final size it will have, so it won't need to be resized on every execution of `append`. For example, like this:

```
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(result.length());
```

You'd better even take in account an extra size for the newline characters. For example, oversizing 5%:

```
StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder((int)(1.05d*result.length()));
```

**Two**: If you just need to write the result out to a file, do not even store it into a StringBuilder:

```
String result = getLargeJSONString(...);
JSONArray results = new JSONArray(result);
try(Writer output=new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF8")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject cleanedResult = JSONSanitizer.sanitize((JSONObject) results.get(i));
        output.write(cleanedResult.toString());
        output.write('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the StringBuilder is unnecessary. I took out the StringBuilder as suggested and there is no more OutOfMemory error.